# What is the name of such type of integral construct, and how do I solve it?

Tags: integration

My math is stone age, and despite being acceptable in research, I couldn't find where to start to solve this integral, or even if it needs something special to solve:

$$ t=\int_{x1}^{xf} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(v^2+2\int_{x1}^{xf} a.dx)}}  dx  $$

Where "t" is time and "a" is acceleration ($a=F/m=kq1q2/mx^2$ from, Coulomb's + Newton's), v is initial velocity, and "x" is distance between ions.

The "final" equation was the (partial) result of the question "How do I get displacement if acceleration depends on displacement?", where I had in mind the attraction/repulsion between ions. Instead, I got time t depending on distance x which is the next best. However, when trying to transform this into an equation, I found that I don't know *what* to look for to study. I do have a good basic idea of Calculus, but I completely lack technique, and when searching, I end up reading stuff I don't really need at the moment (like me landing on 'double integrals' and finding out after some time it is not what I have at hand, or 'multiple', or 'nested'... nothing googling right so far :) ).

1) Is there a name for such construct? Or is it just a normal thing and you solve the inner to $-kq1q2/mx$, apply boundaries and then solve the outer one?

2) If it is not that simple, what technique do I study to solve it?

3) And since we are here, how do I get the opposite, x in terms of t? (I have in mind this might auto-solve once (if!) I get an equation, but I've been wrong before...)

I did try to integrate thru software, which gave me the condition that v can't be 0, which shows I obviously did something wrong since my initial v *can* always be 0.

In case it is relevant, this is where this integral came to be:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320752/how-do-i-get-the-position-at-time-t-if-acceleration-depends-on-position/321041?noredirect=1#comment722262_321041

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a force that depends on distance it's far easier to use conservation of energy to calculate most quantities involved since $F=ma= m\frac{dv}{dt} = m \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = m v \frac{dv}{dx}= m \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}v^2\right)$. Then further note that since the electrostatic force is conservative we have that $F = -\frac{d V}{dx}$ where V represents the potential that causes the force (here the coulomb potential)

Comment: The very first search using some strings I used before +"potential" landed me on a page where distance is not squared anymore (weee faster processing!), and the energy is giving me velocities, and I love you :) The funny part is that I *am* using the conservation of momentum to calculate velocities after collision, but I never thought of entering the energy equations for displacement because I didn't think of them as a "distance" action thing, but an "impact and final velocities" thing :D Many thanks, I will have tons of use for that :)

Comment: Though you apparently just came up with an answer, i would still like to point out that the integrand of your outer integral does not depend on $x$. As initial velocity, $v$ is constant, and $x$ is a dummy variable in the inner integral. So when that integration is performed, there is no more "$x$" to be integrated by the outer integral. So, $$t = \frac{x_f - x_1}{\sqrt{v^2+2\int_{x_1}^{x_f}a\,dx}}$$